# Internal function use cases

Tags: solidity, keyword

What is the main purpose / family of use-cases for the existence of internal functions in solidity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internal Functions cannot be called by other external smart contract or wallet directly. But internal or public function within smart contract and call internal function.

Internal functions are used Mostly in below way.

We write a public function, which do some security checks.

After sucessful security checks the public function calls internal function.

For example:

Here in [ERC20.sol](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol) [`transfer()`](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol#L113) *(public)* function do a security check of `address owner = _msgSender();` *(if sender is owner of tokens)*

and then calls [`_transfer()`](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol#L226) internal function which transfers the token.

You could have done this in once public function. But this is how every code is written in standard format. As `_transfer()` is used many times i.e. in `transferFrom()` public function also calls `_transfer()` internal function.

Comment: I am wondering if what you have written isn't just about use case in which private function modifier could have been used. But as I have read 'internal' allows for usage in sub-contracts. So it seems that in example you have provided we anticipate that we will have some contracts inheriting from ERC20.sol that can use this internal function while it wouldn't be possible with private function.

Comment: Yes. Also quick tip dont use modifier instead use internal functions, this takes less gas fee.